# Rails app can not load the custom app config from lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have defined AppConfig class in `lib` folder like this:

```
// lib/app_config.rb
module AppConfig
  mattr_accessor :title

  def self.configure
    yield self
  end
end
```

Set custom AppConfig:

```
// config/initializers/app_config.rb
AppConfig.configure do |config|
  config.title = "WOW"
end
```

I tried puts AppConfig.title => It works well and write "WOW" in the terminal. But when i use AppConfig.title in my controller:

```
// app/controllers/application_controller.rb#index
render json: { title: AppConfig.title }
```

It returns `{ title: null }`

I don't know why, somebody can help me? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot autoload code in initializers. This is [explained in the guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html):

> While booting, applications can autoload from the autoload once paths, which are managed by the once autoloader. Please check the section config.autoload_once_paths above.
>
> However, you cannot autoload from the autoload paths, which are managed by the main autoloader. This applies to code in config/initializers as well as application or engines initializers.
>
> Why? Initializers only run once, when the application boots. If you reboot the server, they run again in a new process, but reloading does not reboot the server, and initializers don't run again. [...]

If you want to to use your AppConfig class in an initializer you need to to use `require` or use the events that Rails provides so that you code is properly reloaded.

But before you do you should really ask yourself if you actually need to spread your app configuration out in yet another place. YAGNI.